# how to make handler method run 1st in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, callback

In the below method calls from a single object, how to make the handler method to run 1st and then the main method in Objective-C? 
Does it run in Asynchonous or Synchronous way?

Main method    :AuthenticateMobileServer

handler Method :Handler

```
[mobile_Obj authenticateMobileServer:self action:@selector(handler:)];
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm getting what you're asking. But first of all please do use correct naming/capitalization for Objective-C! So please take a look at (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocLanguageSummary.html)
(method names and variable names are in lowerCamelCase! Only class names are in CamelCase)
so it should be `[mobileObj authenticateMobileServer:self action:@selector(handler:)]`

Now to your question. By sending a `authenticateMobileServer:action:` message to mobileObj only that method is executed. `@selector(handler:)` is only a function pointer.